# Calculate vector from dihedral angle.

Tags: vectors

I would basically like to do the reverse of this question: [How do I calculate a dihedral angle given Cartesian coordinates?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47059/how-do-i-calculate-a-dihedral-angle-given-cartesian-coordinates)

I have 3 points, and i would like to find the fourth point that spans the two planes with a given dihedral angle.

If i have points A, B, C, D, than the cross product of vector AB and BC will be the normal vector of the spanned plane of ABC (same goes for BCD), but when i try to do it in reverse, i always fail.

Is there an "easy" solution to this problem?

UPDATE:

So i tried to implement the solution that was given to this question, but i am unable to replicate it. So my four points are a,b,c,d the dihedral is angle, and in principle i should get back the coordinates of point d.

```
a = np.array([5.588, 13.965, -22.320])
b = np.array([4.753, 13.567, -21.196])
c = np.array([3.713, 14.653, -20.905])
d = np.array([2.454, 14.243, -20.787])

angle = dihedral_from_vectors(a, b, c, d)
print(angle) # 2.2737420259103684

u = c - b
v = (b - a) - (np.dot((b - a), u)/u**2)*u

w = np.cross(u, v)

q = v/np.linalg.norm(v)*np.cos(angle)
e = w/np.linalg.norm(w)*np.sin(angle)

print(b + (q-e)) # [  5.2020659   14.45198936 -21.0729811 ]
print(b + (q+e)) # [  4.37411986  13.44621893 -20.27846974]
```

Comment: You cant get point D back, because there are infinite number of points D that generate the same dihedral angle.

Comment: Also, `u**2` in numpy is exponentiation per element, you need to actually use `np.dot(u,u)` instead

Comment: @VasilyMitch And in case the length of CD is known?

Comment: It is still not enough, you need angle $\angle BCD$ too.

Comment: @VasilyMitch I dont really get it. What i want to do is to calculate protein amino acid rotamers. These are given as dihedral coordinates, and a lot of software is able to reconstruct them. I just dont get what am i missing?

Comment: In protein backbone flat angles are fixed, so you do possess of $\angle BCD$

Comment: I see, can you please describe they why i should go if i have angle BCD

Answer (score 1):

Vector $u=BC$ lies on both planes, vector $v=BA-\frac{BA\cdot u}{u^2}u$ lies on $ABC$ and is perpendicular to $BC$. $w=u\times v$ (or $w=BC\times BA$) is a vector perpendicular to the plane $ABC$.

Thus, you can take vector $BD = \frac{v}{|v|}\cos\theta \pm \frac{w}{|w|}\sin\theta$.

You can show that normal $n$ to $BCD$:
$$
n=BC\times BD = \frac{u\times v}{|v|}\cos\theta \pm \frac{u\times w}{|w|}\sin\theta.
$$

Notice, that $|n| = |u|$

And the angle between $n$ and $w$:
$$
n\cdot w = \frac{u\times v\cdot w}{|v|}\cos\theta \pm \frac{u\times w\cdot w}{|w|}\sin\theta = \frac{|u||v||w|}{|v|}\cos\theta = |n||w|\cos \theta
$$

Comment: Definition of vector v is not very clear. (x*u/u**2)*u is just x right? So v = BA-BA which is 0. What am i missing?

Comment: $u(x\cdot u)/u^2$ is not $x$. take $x=(1,0)$ and $u=(1,1)$ as an example

Comment: Sorry, i still dont get it. I updated my question with an example, and my python implementation of your solution. Would you be so kind to take a look and show me what am i doing wrong? Thanks a lot!